# How to add header in Google spreadsheet

Tags: java, google-docs, google-sheets

I am using `gdata-spreadsheet-3.0` jar to enter data in a Google spreadsheet.

I am using

```
(new ListEntry()).getCustomElements().setValueLocal("Header Name", "Value");
```

But I don't want to create the header manually.

I am unable to enter/create the header of the spreadsheet with Java. I’m also unable to enter data using spreadsheet's header (means A B C...).

Can I create a header or can I use spreadsheet's header (means A B C...)?

Comment: I want to set header as Month-year but when i put value like August-2014 it shows 1/8/2014. any solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use the cell objects/feeds to set the values in the header row.

http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#CellFeeds

If that works, then you can hopefully use the list objects/feeds with header names you just set.